# Creating a Login System for Simple GUI game extends Canvas

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, canvas, awt

I have created a game similar to pacman that extends Canvas and implements Runnable.  When compiling and running the game, the game shows a 'Please press enter to start' screen then the game immediately starts.

I want to create a simple login system that allows users to create a username and password.  Then be able to login with that username and start the game.

I got a sample login system working using JDialog but the login only works as a separate project.  It does not display if included in the game.

Is this because Canvas is an awt object but JDialog, JPanels etc are swing?

and what is the easiest way to get a login system working?

(I am new to programming so looking for an easy solution)
Here is the code from the main class:

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable, KeyListener {
private boolean isRunning = false;
private static boolean gameStart = false;
public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = 480;
public static final int boxWidth = 400, boxHeight = 250;
public static final int xx = Game.WIDTH / 2 - boxWidth / 2;
public static final int yy = Game.HEIGHT / 2 - boxHeight / 2;
public static final String TITLE = "Simple Strategic Game";
private Thread thread;
public static Player player;
public static Level level;
public static final int START_SCREEN = 0, GAME = 1;
public static int STATE = -1;
public boolean isEnter = false;
private int time = 0;
private int targetFrames = 30;
private boolean showText = true;

public Game(){
    Dimension dimension = new Dimension(Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);
    setPreferredSize(dimension);
    setMinimumSize(dimension);
    setMaximumSize(dimension);
    addKeyListener(this);
    STATE = START_SCREEN;   
}

private synchronized void start(){
        if(isRunning) return;
        isRunning = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop(){
    if(isRunning) return;
    isRunning = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void tick(){

    if(STATE == GAME){
    player.tick();
    level.tick();
    } else if(STATE == START_SCREEN){
        time++;
        if(time == targetFrames){
            time = 0;
            if(showText){
                showText = false;   
            }else{
                showText = true;
            }
        }
        if(isEnter){
            isEnter = false;
            player = new Player(Game.WIDTH/2, Game.HEIGHT/2);                   //Starts player in middle of screen
            level = new Level("/map/map.png");
            STATE = GAME;
        }
    }
}

private void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null)
    {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);
    if(STATE == GAME){
    player.render(g);
    level.render(g);
    }else if(STATE == START_SCREEN){
        g.setColor(new Color(120,157,213));
        g.fillRect(xx, yy, boxWidth, boxHeight);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 19));
        if(showText) g.drawString("Press Enter to start the Game", xx+60, yy+100);

    }
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();  
}

@Override
public void run() {
    requestFocus();
    int fps = 0;
    double timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double targetTick = 60.0;
    double delta = 0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / targetTick;

    while(isRunning){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;

        while (delta >= 1){
            tick();
            render();
            fps++;
            delta--;
        }
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer >= 1000){
            System.out.println(fps);
            fps = 0;
            timer += 1000;
        }
    }
    stop();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Game game = new Game();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(Game.TITLE);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    game.start();   
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(STATE == GAME){
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) player.right = true;
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) player.left = true;
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) player.up = true;
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) player.down = true;
    } else if(STATE == Game.START_SCREEN){
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            isEnter = true;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) player.right = false;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) player.left = false;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) player.up = false;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) player.down = false;
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: so you want us to code it for you?

Comment: Just wanted a suggestion for what tools I should use.  I tried swing tools but couldn't get it working..

Comment: *"I tried swing tools but couldn't get it working.."* Then you should concentrate on fixing that. Any other tools will present the same challenges. *"I got a sample login system working using JDialog but the login only works as a separate project."* The problem is apparently the IDE That is using you as its slave. Put it aside for the moment and learn how to code Java.

Comment: thanks andrew I will go back to learning the fundamentals

Comment: `static`, `static` everywhere - `static` is not a cross object communication solution and you need to start figuring how not to rely on it